# python process creation and process ID

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can some one suggest what could be the best method to spawn a child process in python?
I have used one method like below.How can I get the pid of child process in below method ? Or how do I know the process been actually created ?

```
def main():
    process = QtCore.QProcess()
    process.start('python', ['./Hello_World.py'])
    time.sleep(5)
    process.kill()
```

Comment: How about [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: Using this method,actually the process been created.But I couldn't get the process id or status of the child process

Comment: popen will work for me .How can I route  stdout to parent process,similar to readyReadStandardOutput.connect() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid).

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-alh'])

print(p.pid)
```

You can also use the instance to [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with the spawned process.

Comment: I've posted it as a comment for you... but I'm also flagging this as *not an answer* :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for pointing out. I have added an example.